# How to fix: Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

in my application I have created SqlRepository to connect to SQL database using EF. And I have used Unity for dependency injection.
SqlRepository constructor looks like this:

```
 public SqlRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
```

And in UnityConfig.cs file I have registered classes like this:

```
  container.RegisterType<IRepository<Product>, SqlRepository<Product>>();
  container.RegisterType<IRepository<ProductCategory>, SqlRepository<ProductCategory>>();
```

Product and ProductCategory are basic classes with properties like Id/Name.

I am getting error Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown. InvalidOperationException: Failed to select a constructor for System.Data.Entity.DbContext
Please help.

Comment: your dbcontext has constructor with or without parameters? container needs to know from where to take `DbContext` object as it is required in constructor

Comment: Here is the DbContext constructor code:  public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

Comment: Your injecting `DbContext` not a `DataContext`, it seems as though you actually want to inject `DataContext` since that's what has the default constructor. So you want `public SqlRepository(DataContext context)`

Comment: Thanks man @JSteward for pointing out "You are injecting DbContext, not a DataContext". Actually DataContext was inheriting DbContext.So in SqlRepository constructor instead of passing DataContext, I was passing DbContext by mistake. Changed it and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Arpit you could have also left it as `DbContext` and just registered the type  `container.RegisterType<DbContext, DataContext>();`